# Rename inherited names in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data frame called noNAN which has a list of 21 columns [class 0....class 20] which I have converted to a table of proportions for each row and saved this as 'percentagePrach'

```
percentagePrach <- round(prop.table(as.matrix(noNAN[,9:29]),1) *100, 1)
```

I wish to rename the inherited column labels for percentagePrach to the following structure [ % class 0, % class 1........ % class 20]

I've tried the following code but I am getting an error relating to the length of 'dimnames' not being equal to the array extent??

```
dimnames(percentagePrach) <- list(colnames(percentagePrach, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "% class "))

Error in dimnames(percentagePrach) <- list(colnames(percentagePrach, do.NULL = FALSE,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

Could anyone elaborate on what array this is referring to?

Could I specify the column names in the original prop.table as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I specify the column names in the original prop.table as an argument?

exactly there is the function `colnames()`

```
colnames(percentagePrach) <- c("newcolname1", "newcolname2", "newcolname3", ...)
```

Comment: Thanks And, this was the first thing I tried and I got some obscure error so I tried an alternative way which didn't work either. It turns out I had too many "," in my code!! Many thanks, I feel like a right jack @ss.

Answer (score 1):

No reproducible example given, but I believe your problem is that the `dimnames` value itself must be (from `?dimnames`):

> ... ‘NULL’ (which is not stored) or a list **of the same length as ‘dim(x)’**.

(emphasis added).  The individual values for each dimension must be

> either ‘NULL’ or a character vector of non-zero length equal to the appropriate dimension

So try `NULL` for the row names (first element) and your desired values for the column names (second element):

```
cn <- colnames(percentagePrach, do.NULL = FALSE, prefix = "% class ")
dimnames(percentagePrach) <- list(NULL,cn)
```

As @and mentions in their answer, if you only want to name one dimension of a matrix/two-dimensional array, you can use `colnames(x) <- ...` or `rownames(x) <- ...` instead of inserting `NULL`s for the appropriate dimensions.

The (very short) help for `?prop.table` suggests you can't rename the dimensions on the fly.